# Using Botan library in C++ with g++: How to compile and link against Botan for my project?

Tags: c++, g++, botan

I am trying to use Botan library in my project. But I don't know how to do so.

Here is my project directory structure:

```
C:.
├───.vscode
├───botan
│   └───internal
└───lib
    ├───botan
    │   ├───.github
    │   │   ├───actions
    │   │   │   └───setup-build-agent
    │   │   └───workflows
    │   ├───build
    │   │   ├───docs
...
```

I am trying to link the botan library to my C++ project using g++. Here is what I have tried:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -Ilib/botan/build/include/botan -Llib/botan -lbotan-3
```

My `main.cpp` file looks like this:

```
#include<botan/aes.h>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: botan/aes.h: No such file or directory
1 | #include \<botan/aes.h\>
|          ^\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
compilation terminated.
```

**Note:**

- I have tried other header files under botan also.
- I have built the botan library successfully.

Comment: `-Ilib/botan/build/include` Or skip all the manual nonsense and let cmake (maybe with Conan or vcpkg) take care of all of that for you.

Comment: @sweenish I am trying to use cmake with vcpkg, doesn't work somehow. It is asking for findbotan.cmake file.